# SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter

Tags: oracle, procedure, sys-refcursor

I have a table contains `(username-primarykey,password,age,gender);`

have to create procedure like `procedure(username in varchar,s_cursor out sys_refcursor);`

procedure has to accept `username` and returns row (`where username=in parameter` )as cursor.

Rule:Cursor must and should be having unique sequence no along with the record it gives. 
example:`(unique no(sequence),username ,password,age,gender)`

Every time procedure should return single record along with uniqueno(sequence)

Comment: How far have you got yourself?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge i can be able to read into but i am unable to store into cursor with the unique(sequence) number.

Comment: You want a different number each time you read a record?  What sort of rule is that?

Comment: each time a record which retrieves from table has to be stored into cursor with unique number i.e sequence number.

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like this, if you need more information you have to provide more details.

Create a sequence for unique no.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE emp_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

Create a procedure which returns `sys_refcursor` as `OUT` parameter and `emp_id` as `IN` parameter

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_employee_details (user_id 
                                                      YOURTABLE.USERNAME%TYPE,
                                               emp_cursor   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    BEGIN
       OPEN emp_cursor FOR
          SELECT emp_seq.NEXTVAL,
                 USERNAME,
                 PASSWORD,
                 AGE,
                 GENDER
            FROM YOURTABLE
           WHERE USERNAME = user_id;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('<your message>' || SQLERRM);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('<your message>' || SQLERRM);
    END get_employee_details;
    /
```

And to execute the procedure from sqlplus

```
variable usercur refcursor;

DECLARE

user_id  YOURTABLE.USERNAME%TYPE;

BEGIN
user_id := 'JON';
get_employees(user_id,:usercur);

END;
/

print usercur
```

Update 1

I assume that you are calling your procedure from sqlplus or from Toad, then you could execute your procedure as

```
variable dcursor refcursor;

DECLARE


p_arrival  DEFAULT_DETAILS.ARRIVALCOUNTRY%TYPE;

BEGIN
p_arrival := '123';
PROCEDURE_SAMPLE(p_arrival,:dcursor);

END;
/

print dcursor
```

Update 2

To execute procedure from SQL Developer, do as

```
var usercur refcursor
exec procedure_sample('AU',:usercur)
print usercur
```